# Can´t show element of an array in a batch file

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I know this question has been answered a lot already but I´ve been looking all of the answers and I thought that I had it right this time but I still can´t echo an element of an array using a variable as the index number. Here´s the code:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set Dir=C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads
set /a counter=0
for /f %%F in ('dir /b "%profDir%"') do echo %%F>>"%profDir%\temp.txt"
for /f %%F in (%profDir%\temp.txt) do (set m[!counter!]=%%F & set /a counter+=1)
echo !m[%counter%]!
pause
```

The temp file has all the file names of the directory I do the search in, but I want to use the "array" for other tasks later, and am unable to continue until I finally get this right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you increment `counter` **after** having assigned the value, the value of `counter` after the second `for` is the next array-entry that would have been created.

Try using

```
set m[
```

to display all of the values that have been set as they appear in the environment

or

```
set /a kounter=counter-1
for /l %%a in (0,1,%kounter%) do echo !m[%%a]!
for /l %%a in (0,1,%kounter%) do call echo %%m[%%a]%%
```

to list them

[note: fixed `%m[%%a]%` to `!m[%%a]!` and added further display method (call...)]

Comment: set m[ returns m[0] to m[27] with their corresponding values, which is the ammount of files in the folder, so the "array" was created properly i think, i added the for loop you suggested and it returns echo is on...27 times. i dont know why this happens

Comment: ok both for loops work, thanks Magoo!!!, but do you know why the code doesn´t wok the way i did it? i dont see what´s wrong with it...

Comment: Your code sets m[0] to m[27]. on the 28th line, you set m[27] and then increment `count` so `count` will be 28. The loop ends, and you try to dosplay m[28] which has not been set. You could fix this by moving the increment **before** the assignment of `m[` so that m[1] to m[28] would be set (and `count` would then represent the **last** m[ filled.)  You could if you wished also `call echo %%m[!count!]%%` within the `for` loop after having set `m[`